# docker container switch from one node to another node without draining or restarting the node

Tags: docker-swarm

How to switch docker container from one node to another node without draining or restarting the node. As everytime I kill container or set docker container unhealthy , the container is started on same node. Purpose of this is to overcome frequent restart of docker on same node?

Answer (score 0):

To specify a node for a container / service you need to specify a constraint `docker service create --name myname --constraint 'node.hostname == dahostname' myimage`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#specify-service-constraints---constraint

and

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_update/#options